# How do I have more than One "Main Node"?

Tags: asp.net, treeview, sitemap

I have a TreeView for my administrator-area as menu.

Here is how it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Here is how it should look:

[image]

So I want to have more than one "MainNodes".

My TreeView have a Sitemap in Background (I need this for my SiteMapPath-control, so I can't delete it and do it without sitemap).

The Sitemap only have 1 "MainNode" and x "Undernodes" with again unendlos "Undernodes".

What can I do?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bind your tree view to another XML file using XMLDataSource ..

Here is a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx).